# jenkins displays username instead of project name

Tags: jenkins

When I enter project configuration in Jenkins (in Firefox), the first field (Project name) displays my Jenkins username instead of actual project name. Every time I change config, I need to change that back to project name (like "foo+tests").

Running latest jenkins version, on ubuntu 12.04.

How to fix that?

Comment: What happens when you open the project's/job's config page in IE? If you see the same, then there's something (script/cron etc) messing with that job's config.xml file. This file is different than config.xml for Jenkins (which sits at $JENKINS_HOME location). Or there may be a scriptler script that you might be using which is replacing the name of the job to your jenkins user name. If I were you, I'd create a cron(2 line shell command called from cron every 5 secs) to send me an alert as soon as something changes the value of the job name in job's config.xml to my email id from ubuntu box.

Comment: It turned out it was KeeFox FF extension that was messing with project name field, not the server-side jenkins config..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was KeeFox FF extension that was messing with project name field in Jenkins.